# How to save alsamixer settings?

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

I work with sound in Ubuntu 14.04. And I can't save the desired settings of Alsamixer. I tried the command **sudo alsactl store 0**, but it has not helped. Alsamixer settings changed after reboot or after connect/disconnect line-in device or a microphone. How correctly save the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `sudo alsactl store 0` stores the settings for card 0 you have to issue a `sudo alsactl restore 0` to restore those saved settings. If you leave the card number off all cards will be affected.

Source: and further information `man alsactl`

Comment: Can I save the settings without the need for alsactl restore command?

Comment: You can save them, but if you want them back restoring is a normal process. You may wish to experiment with other settings mentioned in 'man alsactl', You could also create a startup script that runs the restore for you at every boot.